# Why is this framed box in the shaded environment not showing up?

Tags: framed

I want to place a framed box with some code in a shaded box but for some reason the frame is not showing up. How can I get the frame to show up?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}
\trivlist\item\ignorespaces%
Lorem ipsum 

  \begin{framed}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.9\linewidth}
    \begin{verbatim}
foo bar
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{framed}

cit dolor
\endtrivlist
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean framed box with some shade or framed box with in a shaded box ?

Comment: Framed box within a shaded box. See the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not answer why `frame` doesnt work as expected, but below is a code that gives what you want. Just use `mdframed` instead of `framed.`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}
\trivlist\item\ignorespaces%
Lorem ipsum 

  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=shadecolor]
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.9\linewidth}
    \begin{verbatim}
foo bar
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{mdframed}
cit dolor
\endtrivlist
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `verbatimbox` approach.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}
\trivlist\item\ignorespaces%
Lorem ipsum 

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
\begin{verbbox}
foo bar
\end{verbbox}
\fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{minipage}

cit dolor
\endtrivlist
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the framed box to stretch across the full area, then replace `\fbox{\theverbbox}` with `\fbox{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\theverbbox}}` to get:

[image]

If one upgrades to the `xcolor` package, then an invocation of

```
\fcolorbox{red}{shadecolor!50}{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\theverbbox}}
```

results in

[image]